# What is this 4" to 5" long, light red chili?

Tags: identification, chili

Can you help me identify this chili plant I'm growing? The chilis are 4-5 inches long and not that hot (without the seeds, I can eat one raw without much pain, and I'm not a big spice eater).

*Click on any photo for full size*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

They turn into a light red hue when ripe and get a bit wrinkly in the fridge. In the first picture, the leaves of the chili plant are those on the right, the one above my thumb is from a gardenia (just in case it looks confusing).

Comment: Why doesn't this show up on the home page for non logged-in users? Hard to get an answer this way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like a Cayenne pepper variant (there are many, many types of Cayenne: some thick, some thin, some hot, some not as hot, some that ripen red, purple, yellow, etc.)

Depending on culture, time of year, and variety, some so-called "hot" peppers may just not get all that hot.  I've even had wildly different levels of heat from two peppers on the same plant.

Comment: Thanks, looks plausible enough :) The plant does match the descriptions I've found.